# Show layout before end method

Tags: layout

I need showing a layout per some seconds, and here my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.intro);

    SystemClock.sleep(2000);
    finish();
}
```

but the layout is visible only after the end method, in others words, it is showing after the two seconds and not before the two seconds.

I need showing the layout per 2 second and after close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do so if someone have the same doubt one day I hope this helps.

public class Main extends Activity {

```
private ProgressBar pb;
private Handler h = new Handler();
private int r;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbIntro);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(r = 0;r < 30001;r = r + 1){
                h.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        pb.setProgress(r);
                    }
                });
            }
            startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Menu.class));
            finish();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

}